# pst-asr and "missing \begin{document}" error

Tags: pst-asr

I am trying to use the `pst-asr` package, but it keeps giving me the following error:

> Latex Error: Missing \begin{document}
>
> > l. 282 \define@key[psset]{ASR}{extra gap}{&

Here's my code:

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pstricks, pst-key, pst-asr, graphicx}\psst{everyasr=\tiershortcuts}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textsc{Lipsum} \\
 Titi Livii}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\asr piu \endasr

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't load the pst-key package, it overwrites the definitions of pst-xkey already loaded by pstricks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-asr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textsc{Lipsum} \\
 Titi Livii
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\asr piu \endasr

\end{document}
```